# Cannot read property 'transformFile' of undefined exception vue-native

Tags: android, vue.js, visual-studio-code, package.json, vue-native

I just wanted to try vue-native. However I get this error.
**bundling failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'transformFile' of undefined**

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "vueNativeDeneme",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.10",
    "vue-native-core": "^0.1.4",
    "vue-native-helper": "^0.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.6.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.6.3",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies":{   
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^2.0.0-alpha.20",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.0.0",
    "vue-native-scripts": "0.0.16"
  },
```

Problem solved.

Comment: Could you explain which package is causing the problem and why this solves it, Im having the same problem but the versions numbers are all different.

Comment: This seems bizarre. I just spun up a new vue-native project and after starting it was greeted with this nasty error. 

Do the docs in the vue-native getting started require some updates, or perhaps there are some dependency updates?